# HTML Forms - Prevent some users checking a checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form that users fill in. According to the level of access they have, I want to prevent some of my form being filled in.

If I have a text box I use this `onfocus='blur()'` with a bit of php to check the users privileges .But this does not work for a checkbox.  Can anybody suggest how I can prevent a user from checking a checkbox still having it visible for reference ?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it a `disabled` attribute. As you currently do, use PHP to check for the user's privilege, and only add the attribute if the user can't use the checkbox. Updated my example with some pseudo-PHP to illustrate:

```
<?php if (user can access this field) : ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="some-field" value="some-value" />
<?php else: ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="some-field" value="some-value" disabled="disabled" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I was going to do that (add a PHP example). Well I suppose you win then; you answered first anyways. +1 :)

Comment: @incrediman: heh, thanks. Though to be more precise I'm *second* while Pierre's answer is the *first* ;)

Comment: Also keep in mind that disabling it does not mean you surely recieve it as unchecked on submit. Make sure you also validate the user's rights when you validate/process the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" disabled="disabled"> Disabled Option
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to be disabled only for certain users, do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="useronly" <?php if(!$useraccessgranted) { echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> />
```

or something to that effect. This should not be hard